# Close dropdown when clicking outside

Tags: reactjs, menu, dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGdyW.png)

Here I need to close the dropdown while clicking outside.

```
  const [isWelcomeVisible, setIsWelcomeVisible] = useState(true);
  const [isSelectVisible, setIsSelectVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleWelcome = () => {
    setIsWelcomeVisible(true);
    setIsSelectVisible(false);
  };

  const toggleSelect = () => {
    setIsWelcomeVisible(false);
    setIsSelectVisible(true);
  };
```

```
{activeNavItem !== "DASHBOARD" &&
  activeNavItem !== "LAUNCHPAD" &&
  isWelcomeVisible && (
   <div onClick={toggleSelect} className="welcome__dropdown">
     WELCOME &nbsp;
     <img src={logoDown} alt="" />
   </div>
)}

{isSelectVisible && (
  <div className="toggle__welcome">
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
      onClick={toggleWelcome}
      className="select__class"
     >
      SELECT &nbsp; <img src={logoUp} alt="" />
     </div>
     <div className="welcome__items">
       <Link to="/" className="link">
         <span className="wel__class">MARKETPLACE</span>
           </Link>
            ...
     </div>
  </div>
)}
```

I tried using useRef but did not work. I am expecting closing dropdown after clicking outside.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better approach using ref:

```
export function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
   const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  const onToggle = () => setIsVisible((prev) => !prev);

  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
     if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsVisible(() => false);
     }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);

     return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
    }, []);


  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        <button onClick={onToggle}>Click me</button>
        {isVisible && (
          <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <span>content</span>
            <span>content</span>
            <span>content</span>
            <span>content</span>
          </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*handleClickOutside Function:*

**Purpose:** To detect clicks outside a specific component (the div with the ref reference) and hide the content if such a click occurs.

**Operation:** The function checks if a clicked element (determined by `event.target`) is outside the div referred to by ref.current. If the click is outside, it sets the isVisible state to false, thereby hiding the content.

*useEffect Hook with Event Listener:*

**Purpose:** To set up and clean up an event listener for click events on the entire document.

**Operation:** When the component mounts, it adds a click event listener to the document. This listener triggers handleClickOutside for every click event, allowing the function to check if the click occurred outside the component. The true argument in addEventListener ensures that the event is captured during the capture phase. The cleanup function in useEffect removes the event listener when the component unmounts, preventing memory leaks and unintended behavior.